# shared arrays in OpenMP

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a piece of C++ code with OpenMp but I'm facing some problems.
In fact, my parallelized code is not faster than the serial one.
I think I have understood the cause of this, but I'm not able to solve it.

The structure of my code is like this:

```
int vec1 [M];
int vec2 [N];

...initialization of vec1 and vec2...

for (int it=0; it < tot_iterations; it++) {

if ( (it+1)%2 != 0 ) {

   #pragma omp parallel for

   for (int j=0 ; j < N ; j++) {

  ....code involving a call to a function to which I'm passing as a parameter vec1.....

if (something) { vec2[j]=vec2[j]-1;}

}
}
else {
   # pragma omp parallel for

   for (int i=0 ; i < M ; i++) {

  ....code involving a call to a function to which I'm passing as a parameter vec2.....

 if (something) { vec1[i]=vec1[i]-1;}

 }
 }

 }
```

I thought that maybe my parallelized code is slower because multiple threads want to access to the same shared array and one has to wait until another has finished, but I'm not sure how things really go. But I can't make vec1 and vec2 private since the updates wouldn't be seen in the other iterations...
How can I improve it??

Answer (score 0):

When you speak about issue when accessing the same array with multiple thread, this is called "false-sharing". Except if your array is small, it should not be the bottle neck here as `pragma omp parallel for` use static scheduling in default implementation (with gcc at least) so each thread should access most of the array without concurency except if your "...code involving a call to a function to which I'm passing as a parameter vec2....." really access a lot of elements in the array.

Case 1: You do not access most elements in the array in this part of the code

- Is M big enough to make parallelism useful?
- Can you move parallelism on the outer loop? (with one loop for vec1 only and the other for vec2 only)
- Try to move the parallel region code :

  ```
  int vec1 [M];
  int vec2 [N];

  ...initialization of vec1 and vec2...
  #pragma omp parallel
  for (int it=0; it < tot_iterations; it++) {

      if ( (it+1)%2 != 0 ) {
          #pragma omp for
          for (int j=0 ; j < N ; j++) {
          ....code involving a call to a function to which I'm passing as a parameter vec1.....

              if (something) { vec2[j]=vec2[j]-1;}

          }
      }
  else {
      # pragma omp for
      for (int i=0 ; i < M ; i++) {
      ....code involving a call to a function to which I'm passing as a parameter vec2.....

          if (something) { vec1[i]=vec1[i]-1;}

      }
  }
  ```

This should not change much but some implementation have a costly parallel region creation.

case 2: You access every elements with every thread

I would say you can't do that if you perform update, otherwise, you may have concurency issue as you have order dependency in the loop.